# Swift - Updating variable value depending on the value of another variable

Tags: swift

Im working on a project (Swift), and I have a bit of a problem. So I have a variable "score", property of GameViewModel class. My idea is to update the value of "scoreText" (another property of GameViewModel), every time the value of "score" changes.
My code so far:

```
private(set) var score: Int = 0
private(set) var scoreText = "Score: 0"

private func updateScore(_ isValidRound: Bool){
      score += isValidRound ? GameLayout.validRoundReward : GameLayout.invalidRoundPenalty
      scoreText = "Score: \(score)"
}
```

I feel like there has to be a better way of implementing this: like the "scoreText" observing and updating its value when "score" changes its value (like @Published).

Thank you, for your help!
Cheers

Comment: Property Observers https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html

Comment: A more direct link https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#ID262

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, thank you. That was what I was looking for, cheers!